# Using where clause in copying column data from one table to another in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using the SQL window in phpmyadmin and trying to get data from column `wndef` in table `ismysql` into column `wndef` in table `k2sql2` and ensure that the data coming from `ismysql` is from rows that match `syn_offset` in `k2sql2`.

There are many more rows of data in `ismysql`, but I want the tables to match where column `uoffseta` in `ismysql` equals column `syn_offset` in table `k2sql2`.

Here is the syntax I'm trying:

```
INSERT INTO k2sql2 (wndef)
SELECT wndef
FROM ismysql
where ismysql.uoffset = k2sql2.syn_offset
```

Corrections to my syntax much appreciated.

Comment: INSERT is for adding _new_ rows. This is basic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want an `update` not an `insert`:

```
update k2sql2 join
       ismysql
       on ismysql.uoffset = k2sql2.syn_offset
    set k2sql2.wndef = ismysql.wndef;
```